# How do I run specific commands every time a new user is added

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

Currently, I have to create a directory on drive /data to store big datasets on a different drive (to separate it from the /home directory) for each user that is created and assign access rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create or modify file /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local

This file is script.

chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local